# Can I install files onto the desktop of my machine as part of my Visual Studio 2019 project install so that they can be deleted by the user?

Tags: visual-studio, installation-package

I have catered a visual studio project that deposits help files onto the desktop of the target machine as part of the installation, however when these files are removed the installed software will no longer launch without a reinstallation. Would anyone know if it is possible to mark these files within the installation so that they can be deleted by the user so that the operation of the software is not affected. David

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with your application, not with the installer. What error do you get if these files are missing? Also, if you need to do this, I would suggest you install the files to the application directory and just place shortcuts on the desktop.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, there is no error the project just goes through a reinstallation. The same happens if the project exe file is deleted, as you would expect. It is as if the desktop files are tagged as structural files for the overall application and so they cannot be moved or altered in any way. Its probably just a function of the installer and the integrity of all the project components are checked on startup and if any are altered it interprets this as damage and so initiates a reinstallation. David

Comment: That then depends on the way your installer works. But anyway, I would suggest you create shortcuts on the desktop instead. If the user deletes those, that shouldn't cause any issue.

Comment: Hi I tried a link but deleting the link had the same effect, in the end I put the files out of the way and now give the option to create a copy onto the desktop for the user.  As this copy was not part of the installation it dose not suffer from the limitations of the directly installed files. This works fine intact my customer prefers it so that worked out in the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think to solve your problem, you should describe more detailed what kind of installer you use and how you have configured it. This is not the standard behavior for the installation packages I know.